# How can I visualize a base64 image in Postman?

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, postman

I have a request that returns a this is my postman output base64 string. Is there a way to visualize the image in Postman?

[image]

Comment: Please share actual printed text and not images so the community can better analyze your code and issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Postman's visualize feature](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/). I've created a [public sample to demonstrate this](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/request/19391207-cda46a75-b698-4b50-aecf-0eade15f6dce). To do this, I've set a sample base64 image on the body of the request and using [Postman Echo](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/published-postman-templates/documentation/631643-f695cab7-6878-eb55-7943-ad88e1ccfd65), it just returns the same value on the data field. With that, I just read the data and use a visualizer to present it:

```js
// Image is found on the respose on the data field
const imageBase64 = pm.response.json().data;

// This is just a simple template with a placeholder for a base64 image
var template = `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,{{image}}" />`


// Set visualizer - Inits handle bars and passes the image variable to the template
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `data`
    image: imageBase64
});
```

This will look like the following, if you click the `Visualize` tab:

[image]