# Postman Base64 to img

Tags: javascript, postman

is there any possible way to convert base64 image, which I receive in the JSON response body to an image inside postman?

[The JSON response with the base64 that I Receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMRlZ.png)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: What do you mean "inside postman"?

Comment: Sorry, its my first question here, 

I have a request that returns base64 string. Is there a way to visualize the image in Postman?

Comment: Probably not. It's an API client, not a full development environment.

Comment: if you update your question with your `label and long string` and `URL` of Postman, it may help to understand your situation.
Here is how to add a code snipped (text) in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
Create code fences with three backticks ``` or tildes ~~~, one on a line before the code, and one on a line after

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73645893/10839134